# Public Project/Default Permissions with GitLab

Tags: permissions, gitlab

I'm comparing Gitorious with Gitlab, and while there are many things I like about Gitlab, it has a very fundamental problem. For every new repository, the creator needs to manage who has access to that repository.

Our model is rather simple: if you have access to gitlab, you have access to most repositories. Only a few repositories would be closed off, and we don't even need them on gitlab. Gitorious support that model, but I haven't seen any way of doing that on gitlab.

Can it be done? If so, how?

Comment: This question is now outdated, Gitlab has allowed public projects since 6.2, which was three or more years ago.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Public repositories are something the developers have been resistant to adding support for.  They don't want to gitlab to be a github competitor.
See https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/12

Team support is something that is still under development.  Hopefully what your are requesting will be implemented at some point. 
See:
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/739

Until the better Team support gets implemented your best bet might be to use a script like:
https://gist.github.com/1722391 to add users to all projects.  This is the approach I'm currently using.

or use the new rake commands to bulk add users:

```
rake add_user_to_project_teams[email]  # Add user to as a developer to all projects
rake add_users_to_project_teams        # Add all users to all projects, system administrators are added as masters
```

Comment: Have you updated the script to add users to all projects? The current  one on Github is rather old and is not working with Gitlab 2.8 for me.

Comment: According to https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/2746 that issue has been closed and the teams feature has been implemented.

Answer (score 2):

For Gitlab there are also two Rake tasks which can manage bulk adding of users to repositories:

```
rake add_user_to_project_teams[email]  # Add user to as a developer to all projects
rake add_users_to_project_teams        # Add all users to all projects, system administrators are added as masters
```

Answer (score 2):

A fork of Gitlab allowing public repositories has sprung up: https://github.com/ArthurHoaro/Public-GitLab

Answer (score 1):

Public projects have been allowed since GitLab 6.2.

Public projects were the most requested feature on the GitLab uservoice group, see http://gitlab.uservoice.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/3159951-allow-public-repositories